# Resize two DIVs Relative to Window Size

Tags: jquery

I currently have one DIV resizing to the full height of the window whenever a user resizes their browser like so:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#selected-folders-area").height($(window).height()-350);
});
```

**NOTE:** The `-350` accounts for the header content

I want to add a second DIV to this page and when the browser is resized, both DIVs need to share the size of the window, filling it with their own heights to the bottom of the window.

I'm not sure if I'm being clear enough, so let me know if you need me to expand.

Comment: What's not clear is why you don't do it ? What's the problem ? It seems like just a small adjustement from what you have.

Comment: Are the div set side by side, or one atop the other? If one above the other, there seems to be an answer for that already below.

Comment: Please clarify your objective. The div is not resizing to "the full height of the window" if it's resizing to 350px LESS than the full height of the window.

Comment: Dystroy's answer below worked perfectly for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with this ?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var h = $(window).height()-350;
    $("#div1,#div2").height(h/2);
});
```

Note that if you want resizing proportional to content... well... that's one of those cases where a table for layout is hard to beat.

You could have different sizes like this :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var h = $(window).height()-350;
    $("#div1").height(h*0.45);
    $("#div2").height(h*(1-0.45));
});
```

Comment: Quick question - say I wanted one of those DIVs to always be a little larger than the other DIV. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var availableHeight = $(window).height()-350;
    var usedHeight = $('#div1').outerHeight() + $('#div2').outerHeight();
    var remainingHeight = availableHeight - usedHeight;
    //distribute remaing height to the divs as you like,this is 50/50
    //note that hight will decrease if it takes more than widow height already
    //if dont want that add your condition
    $("#div1,#div2").each(function(){
        $(this).height($(this).height() + remainingHeight/2);
        });

});
```